# Jquery Toggle .CSS not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the .css property so that the css transitions will animate on click. For some reason this is not working. This action needs to toggle.

```
 $("button.subnav-toggle").click(function(){              
          $(".subnav").toggle(
            function() {
              $(".subnav").css({'top':'0'});
              alert("something");
            }, function() {
              $(".subnav").css({'top':'-150px'});
          })
        });
```

Comment: _How_ is it not working? What do you expect it to do and what does it actually do?

Comment: @Which jquery version are you using?

Comment: Toggle has been removed in the [version 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Comment: Using the latest version of JQuery

Comment: The expected action is to change the .css from 0 to -150 and back. I am using the transition property in CSS3 so that every time the "top" position changes the div.subnav will animate up and down.

Comment: I've editted my answer per your clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about toggling a class with these positions?

Comment: Something like $(".subnav").toggleClass(theclass); and assign it the top value your looking for on the first click. -150px?

Comment: Yes it will, just make sure you have the transition calls set up on your subnav class and it should animate, you may have make the top attribute important on the class your toggling to override the other classes top attribute. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That sounds perfect. I will try this.

Comment: Don't forget to notify us as to which answer worked for you when you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

`.toggle` won't do a transition. You could use `.animate` though:

```
$("button.subnav-toggle").click(function(){  
      $(this).animate({top:'-150px'})
});
```

**Revision:**

```
$("button.subnav-toggle").click(function(){  

    var top = $(this).css('top');
    var topTo = (top == 'auto' || top == '0px') ? '-150px' : '0px';
    $(this).css('top', topTo)
});
```

Fiddled here: http://jsfiddle.net/mhfaust/K5hEb/

Comment: I need too toggle between two positions because it is a dropdown menu i am trying to animate. The position depends on the click of one button.

Comment: Revised according to this clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button.subnav-toggle').click(function () {
        var visible = $('.subnav').is(":visible");
        $('.subnav').slideToggle(500);
        if (!visible) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.subnav').offset().top
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```